# Improve the response time of AWS Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have been using Couchbase for about two years but we finally decided to switch to Amazon DynamoDB service for many reasons.
Now I started the migration of data to dynamodb. First everything was alright and going as expected, but after some time the response time from dynamo is getting higher and higher and the migration process is getting slower by time.
I tried to change my strategies but with no luck.
What can I do to increase the response time?

Basically I am scanning an SQL table getting 100 items per query then asking Couchbase to retrieve the data I want about these 100 items. At first I was getting high response times (as shown in the image bellow).

The following info might help:

- I am running the migration code on an ec2 micro server running Ubuntu 14.04 with node v 4.4.1.
- After looking at the graphs I started measuring the time for each dynamodb request (so I don't know what is the average was at first), the average response time is 800 ms for about 150,000 requests (get & put only, no batch commands or queries)
- I am storing the items in two tables one with integer hash key and the other is with integer hash and sort keys
- The second table is a huge one (having about 4.4 millions of items and counting)

[image: An image shows how the consumed capacity decreased overtime]

Comment: You are "scanning a SQL table"? But you only list Couchbase and DynamoDB, which aren't SQL databases. Do you mean to say that you are performing a full table scan of a DynamoDB table? It seems to me that your entire problem is simply due to the provisioned throughput on the DynamoDB table being too low. Your provisioned throughput settings are probably the most important information related to this question, and you didn't include that information.

Comment: Due to how our system is designed we use Mysql and Couchbase combined, in Mysql we store simple data but in Couchbase we store the whole json object. Now we want to get rid of couchbase and move to Dynamodb. And as it shows in the attached image the provisioned throughput for this table is 125 (the red horizontal line) and the consumed throughput is getting lower and lower (it started around 100 then decreased to 20 then to less than5)

Comment: If you have what know a "hot partition keys" your provisioned capacity wouldn't matter since single shard can only handle N number of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Vor for mentioning the "Hot partition keys" I have made further readings and in reference to the [Guidelines for Working with Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.DataUpload) I have followed what they are recommending and also I distributed my requests into batch requests made the difference.
Thank you all for your help.